# How to unlock bootloader on samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, bootloader, bootloader-lock

Before you try to install any custom ROM on your device, you need to unlock the phone’s bootloader, which is a code executed before any OS (operating system) launch. The notion of a bootloader is unanimous to all operating systems worldwide and includes systems running on your personal computers, laptops, tablets, smartphones, smartwatches and everything that has OS on it

HTC website has a section for developers where you can grab SDK; you just need to find your phone’s model. Samsung website does not offer such luxury, Sony Mobile website offers a section for users looking to unlock their Sony’s bootloader.

- So, For Samsung Devices How to unlock Bootloader?
- any useful reference *links* or *comments* or *answers* will much be appreciated :)

Note: am using Samsung note 3 neo

Answer (score -1):

To unlock the boot loader you need to have the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) with all the packages installed and configured.

Later once the configuration is done properly then you can connect your device and enable USB Debugging under the options.

1. Download Modaco’s Superboot files and save them to your computer.
2. Once downloaded, extract it by right clicking and extract all.
3. On your phone, click on Settings > Developer Options > Turn USB Debugging On.
4. Plug the device in to your computer via USB cable.
5. Open the superboot folder that we just extracted (until you see the folder with fastboot-windows inside it), then hold the shift key down on your computer and right click any blank area.
6. Now, select open command window here.
7. In the command prompt, type the following with hitting enter at the end of each line.

`adb-windows reboot bootloader` (and wait for the device to reboot)

`fastboot-windows oem unlock`

(If it gets stuck at waiting for device here, download and install PDANet on your computer, once installed, unplug then plug the device back in and see if that fixes it)

Once it runs the device should display a screen asking you if you
    are sure. Click yes using the volume buttons. The device will go
    back to the bootloader screen but say unlocked at the bottom.

Comment: ur welcome but before doing that please take up the backup if not done properly you will lose all the data

Comment: did you get this from xda ??

Comment: no the unlockr here's the [link](http://theunlockr.com/2011/12/14/how-to-root-the-samsung-galaxy-nexus/)

Comment: does it applicable for normal Samsung device since the link saying that its for samsung galaxy nexus device

Comment: Samsung galaxy and nexus are completely different models whereas Galaxy is manufactured by Samsung and Nexus is manufactured by Lg but branded as Google. So it will work on your Samsung device also. Follow this link regarding nexus devices-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Nexus and this link regarding the galaxy devices-http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy

Comment: will it work for Note 4 ?

Comment: @Dima yes it should and don't forget to download the respective android packages (i.e the android version of your device should be there in the ADT package installed in order to unlock and make sure you have a backup at handy just in case it goes haywire)

Comment: @user285oo6 10x, but what extra stuff do i need except the adt? i installed android sdk via `brew`, do i need to download anything else? btw, `adb shell`, `adb pull` all that stuff works fine with my note 4, does it mean this will work too?

Comment: as the adb shell works fine then you are good to go (usually adb shell requires the USB debug drivers to connect through which the device gets connected with the ADT).

Comment: doesnt work..  its stuck on 'waiting for device' in the fastboot

Comment: p.s. tried on mac and on windows, both without pdanet and with it

Comment: @Dima have  you enabled `USB DEBUGGING` in developer option ?

Comment: @WingedPanther yes

Comment: In my Samsung J3 (SM-J320M) the command "adb-windows reboot bootloader" restarts normally without going into bootloader mode.
And "fastboot-windows oem unlock" just waits forever.

Comment: which Modaco files?  Can you give a URL?

Comment: on samsung j5 2016, `adb reboot bootloader` goes into `Odin Mode, downloading do not turn Off target` ?!!! (I'm using linux but `adb` should have the same effect as `adb-windows`)

Comment: `adb reboot bootloader` (linux) reboots into the system

Comment: `fastboot-windows oem unlock` there is no fastboot with samsung gadgets